# How can I create fields in form based on a parameter set up in html 5 / angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

Our application UI is developed using HTML 5 and angular js and I am quite new to UI designing.

We have a field to input the customer contact number in the form. The format of the field depends on the country that the application is running. Since we use an SIMD architecture, we have decided to hold the country format and the length as a database parameter.

For instance, in MY the contact can be input into 3 fields, operator, contact value and extension while in India it is STD code and then contacts number.
So for MY, the contact should have 3 fields to input and for India, it should have 2 fields.

I have searched on how to add fields dynamically in HTML 5 but have not found anything that would help in our requirement.

Any leads would be helpful. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is `ng-repeat` which is an angular-js service that allows you to repeat a certain HTML code depending on an array. And after creating the fields you then need to store the value somewhere, which calls for another array constructed with a simple for loop.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3b9dpm/1/